# Codeigniter AND OR AND

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

It is posible to do: (condition 1 AND condition2) OR (condition3 AND condition4) in codigniter?

I try:

```
$this->db->where(condition1 - condition2);
$this->db->or_where(condition3 - condition4);
```

But this is: (condition1 AND condition2) OR (condition3 OR condition4)

Comment: Honestly I did not realize there is no straight forward way to group queries in Codeigniter until I just looked it up. I've been using [Datamapper ORM](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) for CI for quite some time, check it out some day I think you will enjoy it (and grouping clauses is easy with it).

Answer (score 5):

Just write it out in your where

```
$this->db->where("(condition1 AND condition2) OR (condition3 AND condition4)");
```

this will still escape data and you don't have to fool with the or_where method.

Answer (score 3):

yes it is possible,for convenience take whatever conditions you want to used into one variable

```
$where ="(condition 1 AND condition2) OR (condition3 AND condition4)";
$this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try like this :::::?

```
$this->db->where(COND1);
$this->db->where(COND2);
$this->db->or_where(COND3); 
$this->db->where(COND4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$first="(COND1 AND COND2)";
$second= "(COND3 AND COND4)";

$query=$this->db->where($first)->or_where($second)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal query like so:

```
$query="SELECT *
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.col=table2.col
WHERE (table1.whatever=? AND table1.hello=?) OR (table2.foo=? AND table2.pizza=?)
LIMIT 1";
$params=array();
$params[]='whatever';
$params[]='world';
$params[]='bar';
$params[]='cheese';


$result=$this->db->query($query,$params);
$result=$result->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP5 then the following code will fix your problem.

```
$this->db->select("*")
->where("condition_1 && condition_2")
->or_where("condition_3 && condition_4");
```

Or use the following code will also works.

```
$this->db->where("condition_1 ");
$this->db->where("condition_2");
$this->db->or_where("condition_3 "); 
$this->db->where("condition_4 ");
```