# select from table or where within and operator in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In mysql there is select * from table where condition and (condition or condition).
Does this also has a code for codeigniter?
example pseudo code

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table");
$this->db->where("condition", $var):
.... now the second where should be --> and (condition or condition)
```

Comment: what about the or_where? or you can just use the query function to write your whatever.

Comment: I guess my answer got upvoted but I just realized I don't think it actually answers your question - check these out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981351/codeigniter-and-or-and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056303/combining-mysql-and-or-queries-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

To query by multiple conditions pass them in an array like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where(array('condition'=>$var_1, 'condition_2'=>$var_2, 'condition_3'=> $var_3)):
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array(); //returns result as array
```

However it depends on your specific query, as certain types of queries/conditions don't work in this type of format.

EDIT: this is what you are looking for though:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where('condition_1'=>$var_1);
$this->db->where("(condition_2=1 OR condition_2=2)", NULL, FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: i think this is what im looking. im gonna try this.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->where('condition',$var);
$this->db->or_where(array('condition'=>$var,'condition'=>$var));
$qry = $this->db->get("table");
print_r($qry->result());
```

All the best.

Comment: you have to get a `result` or `row`, if you just do `->get` it won't work

Comment: i expect him to know that..wat is wanted is the precedence of "and" and "or"...thanks for the suggestion anyways..i updated for better

Comment: it should be $this->db->where() where in mysql it is where condition AND (condition or condition)

Comment: it works exactly lyk dat...where condition and (condition or condition)...it is tested and works perfectly..